A father is asked to assassinate a political character or his daughter will be shot
This is a movie from the early 2000s, possibly late 90s, English, Hollywood.
It begins by what seems as two persons (a man and a woman) scanning an airport for candidates. They select a man with his little daughter. We don't know why they selected him until much later.
The father is separated from his daughter and is then asked to shoot a political person (a president lady), because they need to have the crime blamed on the wrong man.
The father tries to reject the request, but the captors threaten to kill his little daughter if he misses his chance to shoot the lady.
I distinctly remember one scene where the father almost got to his daughter (who is asleep) but the lady sitting one seat back shows him a bulking object from the seat leather and tells him something like: If this was a .45 then the shot will exit the seat and land in your daughter's brain. But if this was a .12 (or something else, I am not good with gun caliber), then the bullet will exit the seat, enter your daughter's brain, exits the brain, and go through the dashboard of the car and exit it as well..."
The father upon hearing all that, re-considers and goes back to resume his mission.
I can't remember how he manages to fool the captors, and does not shoot the president lady, and at the same time saves his daughter. But he might have befriended a lady throughout the movie, and she might have helped.
Does any of that ring a bell?

This is Nick of Time (1995)  with Johnny Depp

An unimpressive, every-day man is forced into a situation where he is told to kill a politician to save his kidnapped daughter.

Wikipedia:

The film opens with Gene Watson (Johnny Depp), a mild-mannered, widowed accountant arriving with his daughter Lynn at the Union Station in Los Angeles [Note not an airport but similar] . As Watson makes a pay phone call informing an unidentified person that his train was late, two mysterious strangers in suits, known only as Mr. Smith (Christopher Walken) and Ms. Jones (Roma Maffia), survey the station from a catwalk, discussing a yet-to-be-elaborated scheme. Noticing Watson retaliate against a skater who was harassing his daughter, Smith and Jones set their sights on him and swiftly approach the pair. Showing a badge, the two strangers convince Watson that they are police officers and whisk both father and daughter into a van without justification. Once in the vehicle, Watson begins to notice things are not right and gets nervous, but Smith subsequently pistol whips him in the leg to get his attention. Smith then informs Watson that they will kill his daughter by 1:30 p.m. unless he murders a woman depicted in a photograph. He soon learns that the woman is State Governor Eleanor Grant and realizes that killing her would be a suicide mission.

